# Want equal spaces between repeating symbols in mathmode, how I disable kerning?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, kerning

Trying to get equal spacing between repeating characters in mathmode.
I tried using the microtype package and use the DisableLigatures function, it should
disable kerning and would expect equal spaces between the symbols, however this is not the case. For example, the last two stars in a four star row are closer together.

This is my MVP:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{family=*}

\begin{document}
\section{expert levels}
expert ($\star\star\star\star\star$)\\
proficient ($\star\star\star\star$)\\
competent ($\star\star\star$)\\
advanced beginner ($\star\star$)\\
beginner ($\star$)\\
\end{document}
```

And this is my output:
[image: latex math spacing fail]

Comment: use `{\star}{\star}{\star}` this is a duplicate, I'll find..

Comment: Indeed, this was a duplicate question, It didn't occur to me that I should be searching for \star while trying to identify duplicates :D

Comment: You don't want to disable ligatures, of course. I'd define `\ExplSyntaxOn \NewDocumentCommand{\stars}{m}{\textborn\prg_replicate:nn { #1 - 1 } { \,\textborn } } \ExplSyntaxOff` so you can type `\stars{5}` or whatever (so long as the argument is a positive integer). Instead of `\textborn` you may use `$\star$`, if you prefer.